# I have a class in java which performs a check, and I want to store every time it does that without making more instances. How should I implement this?

Tags: java, oop

sorry if my question is worded weirdly, but I don't really know a better way to describe the problem I'm having without using more words and showing my code.

It is a design problem, and first I will explain it more in detail, then provide some code. My java program is structured as such:

I have class ItemsFile which is essentially a class that reads from a file that I am using for my program, and returns a list (of items) from a file. I have one, final instance of the ItemsFile class in my main class. I have another class, called InventoryChecker which depends on that list of items that is gotten from ItemsFile. There are several other classes that depend on the instance of the ItemsFile object I have, and I pass it into their constructors. There are also other classes that depend on InventoryChecker, which I also make an instance of in main after ItemsFile is initialized, then pass it as a parameter.

The purpose of inventoryChecker is basically this: It has a function called CheckInventory(inventory) which accepts an inventory, and checks to see if the inventory contains any of the items listed in the ItemsFile, and if so, that method returns true.

The problem is this: I have a list of inventories that I am continuously looping through, and when I have an inventory that causes CheckInventory to return true, it does that constantly and logs the same thing over and over, which floods my log file. I want to only have it log that again if there is something very different about the inventory, like a different item in ItemsList is found in it. It doesn't actually have to read from the file to do this, it is totally fine if it logs the same inventories again after the program restarts, and there are duplicates in the log file because of that.

So here are the solutions I thought about:

1.) I could make a static hashmap inside of the inventorychecker class, which would be constant across all of the instances of inventoryChecker if there end up being multiple, and basically just add the owner of said inventory (think of the owner like a Player in a game, who might have an inventory, and the player is the owner of said inventory) as the Key, and the items that were found as the Value (in some sort of container), then each time the CheckInventory method runs, I see if the player is already in there - and if so, I don't return true if the inventory hasn't changed.

The pro to this method is the fact that it would be easy to implement and would probably work pretty well for now, but the con is that it would be that say I have several lists of inventories later on, and for one of them, I want this behavior to be a bit different (maybe it returns true if anything in the inventory changes, not just if there are more contraband items, or maybe it even just returns true every time).

2.) Change InventoryChecker so that for each inventory, a new InventoryChecker object is made, and add a compareTo method to it, and then have a list somewhere else where each instance of InventoryChecker that returned true is added. Then, whenever a new InventoryChecker returns true, I could go loop through that list and use the Compare method to see if any of them are equal, and if so - i don't add it, but if not - I do add it.

This seems like a bad way of doing it, because it would be creating a ton of objects, not to mention the InventoryChecker objects are made in other classes, but inventoryChecker needs itemFile's item list, and that would be another problem because then I would have to get that instance of itemFile into all the classes that use inventoryChecker - maybe making them dependent on it, and I just don't like this method at all. I don't really know if there's any pro to this method, but I just thought of it as a possibility and maybe I haven't realized something that would make this method good.

Both of these seem to have a few problems with them, and I'm not a huge fan of either implementation.

Here's my code as of right now:

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
    
    //filename of the yml file that contains all of the materials and quantities
    final String itemsYmlFileName = "items.yml";
    //file that stores the items to be used all throughout this plugin
    final ItemsFile itemsFile = new ItemsFile(this, itemsYmlFileName);
    
    /*
     * This function executes when the plugin is loaded/enabled,
     * due to the server starting, after a restart, or after a
     * plugin reload, etc.
     */
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        //this will be the inventoryChecker object passed to ContainerScanner and playerScanner. It's
        //best to get this here because it can be initialized with the itemsFile
        InventoryChecker inventoryChecker = new InventoryChecker(itemsFile);
        
        //register containerScanner event because it uses InventoryCloseEvent from bukkit.
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new ContainerScanner(inventoryChecker), this);
        
        //Register PlayerScanner as a bukkit task so that it will execute the run() function on 
        //regular intervals. This is a synchronous task.
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        BukkitTask playerScan = new PlayerScanner(inventoryChecker).runTaskTimer(this, 500L, 100L);
        
        //set AddItem as the executor for this command so that it's onCommand() function is used
        //when a player types a command.
        this.getCommand("addItem").setExecutor(new AddItem(itemsFile));
    }
    
    /*
     * This function executes when the plugin is disabled due to
     * the server shutting down, restarting, reloading plugins, etc.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        //save any changes to the items Yml file
        itemsFile.saveFile();
    }
}
```

InventoryChecker.java:

```
public class InventoryChecker {
    
    private HashMap<Material, Integer> itemList;
    
    //prevent default constructor from being used:
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private InventoryChecker() {}
    
    /*
     * This constructor accepts a items file object, and will use that to read the Yml file that
     * contains all of the items and quantities to check for, and that will be used to check
     * inventories.
     */
    public InventoryChecker(ItemsFile itemsFile) {
        itemList = itemsFile.getItemsList();
    }
    
    /*
     * This constructor accepts a hashmap of Materials and Integers. The keys in this map
     * (materials) will be what the inventorychecker will check for in the inventory. The
     * values (integers) in this map will be the quantities that set off alerts. 
     */
    public InventoryChecker(HashMap<Material, Integer> items) {
        itemList = items;
    }
    
    /*
     * This function checks the inventory passed as a parameter to see if it contains any
     * materials over the set quantities, and returns true if so. The materials and quantities
     * to check for were passed during construction either as a itemsfile or a regular HashMap.
     */
    public boolean checkInventory(Inventory inv) {
        //cannot check inventory if it is null
        if(inv == null)
            return false;
        
        //tally all of the items in the inventory, and put them in the hashmap
        HashMap<Material, Integer> inventoryItems = tallyItems(inv);
        
        //loop through every entry in the itemList (hashmap of items to be checked)
        //and see if the player has any of the materials in a quantity that is 
        //greater than the value set in the config file
        for(Entry<Material, Integer> itemListEntry : itemList.entrySet()) {
            //this will be equal to null if the item is not in their inventory
            Integer i = inventoryItems.get(itemListEntry.getKey());
            
            //if it's equal to null, go on to the next item
            if(i == null)
                continue;
            
            //if an item is found, return true, they have a material in greater
            //quantity than listed in the config file.
            if(i > itemListEntry.getValue())
                return true;            
        }
        
        //return false, nothing was found
        return false;
    }
    
    /*
     * This function will accept an Inventory, and it will return a HashMap containing
     * each unique material found in the inventory as the keys, and the total amount of
     * the material in the inventory as the value:
     */
    private HashMap<Material, Integer> tallyItems(Inventory inv){
        //omitted to shorten post
    }
}
```

PlayerScanner.java (relies on inventoryChecker, this class scans through a list of players and checks each inventory. This is the list of inventories I mentioned above, where I don't want to continuously log the same player over and over):

```
public class PlayerScanner extends BukkitRunnable{
    
    private InventoryChecker inventoryChecker;
    
    //prevent usage of the default constructor, this class depends on
    //a valid InventoryChecker being passed
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private PlayerScanner() {}
    
    public PlayerScanner(InventoryChecker inventoryChecker) {
        this.inventoryChecker = inventoryChecker;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            //get their inventory/echest and have the inventorychecker
            //see if there are any suspicious quantities of materials in it
            boolean inv = false;
            boolean ender = false;
            inv = inventoryChecker.checkInventory(player.getInventory());
            ender = inventoryChecker.checkInventory(player.getEnderChest());
            
            if(inv || ender) {
                utility.sendAlertMessage("Player: " + player.getName() + "has illegal items in their Inventory or Echest!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ContainerScanner.java - another class that uses inventorychecker, except this one is an EventHandler which basically just runs the onClose() method any time a container is closed by a player, then checks that container's inventory:

```
public class ContainerScanner implements Listener{
    
    private InventoryChecker inventoryChecker;
    
    //disable default constructor
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ContainerScanner() {}
    
    public ContainerScanner(InventoryChecker inventoryChecker) {
        this.inventoryChecker = inventoryChecker;
    }
    
    /*
     * this runs any time the InventoryCloseEvent is triggered, and it
     * scans that inventory
     */
    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.MONITOR)
    public void onClose(InventoryCloseEvent e) {
        
        //if it was an ender chest, don't check because ender chests will be scanned
        //regularly with the player's inventory.
        if(e.getInventory().getType().equals(InventoryType.ENDER_CHEST))
            return;
        
        //send inventory to get checked
        inventoryChecker.checkInventory(e.getInventory());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a dedicated stack exchange site to code review. It might be a good place to start.

Comment: This is way too broad a question for both Stack Overflow and Code Review.  I have the dual problem of not understanding your complete application and not understanding the details of your application.